# (Variable Change) - How to apply Gauss Theorem or Stokes to get volumes?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

> Calculate $$I = \iiint_V  \frac{1}{(xyz)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^{-6}+y^{-8}+z^{-10}}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
>
> We know $\Omega$ is tuple $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $x>0$ , $y>0$ , $z>0$

I don't now how to use Stokes Theorem or Gauss-Divergence Theorem. I think that i need a surface for get integration limits or $\vec{n}$.

Thank you so much

Edit:

$\Omega$ is a function limited on the entire first octant.

$\Omega$ is the function and $V$ is "Volume" closed on this function.

I understand "Calculate this Volume". I get this exercise in a Multivariable calculus test. I really don't know how to propose this problem. I think i need more information for calculate I. Maybe my teacher have been wrong?

The exactly problem was: I translated this from Spanish to English.

> Calcula
> $$I = \iiint_V  \frac{1}{(xyz)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^{-6}+y^{-8}+z^{-10}}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ siendo $\Omega$ las ternas de números reales $(x,y,z)$ tales que $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$.

Edit 2:

I asked my teacher how to resolve this. He answered me that I have to make an easly variable change. Sorry for my mistake, we don't need Divergence Theorem. I will try with the following change but I think that I won't resolve this integrate.

\begin{array}
& x = a \rho \sin^p{\varphi} \cos^q{\alpha}
\\ y = b \rho \sin^p{\varphi} \sin^q{\alpha}
\\ z = c \rho \cos^p{\varphi}
\end{array}

Comment: So is $V$ the entire first octant?

Comment: I still don't understand what $\Omega$ is.  The only function I see in the the problem is $$(x,y,z)\mapsto \frac{1}{(xyz)^2}\frac{1}{1+x^{-6}+y^{-8}+z^{-10}}$$ Is this what you mean by $\Omega$?

Comment: Please give the problem *exactly* as stated in the exam.

Comment: It seems like $V$ in the problem statement is supposed to be $\Omega$ since there is no mention of $V$.  I don't see how the divergence theorem could possible apply.  So far as I know the theorem only applies to compact domains.  Also, how could you find a function $f$ such that $div f$ is the integrand?  I have no idea how to even approach this.